# c# printing after call methods

Tags: methods, printing, instance, var, ref

```
   public class A
{
    public int A1 { get; set; }
    public int A2 { get; set; }
}

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        int i = 0;
        Method1(i);
        Console.WriteLine($"i={i}");
        var str = "This is a string";
        Method2(str);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        var a = new A()
        {
            A1 = 5,
            A2 = 6
        };
        Method3(a);
        Console.WriteLine($"a.A1={a.A1}, a.A2={a.A2}");
        Method4(a);
        Console.WriteLine($"a.A1={a.A1}, a.A2={a.A2}");
        Method5(ref a);
        Console.WriteLine($"a.A1={a.A1}, a.A2={a.A2}");
      
        
    }
 private static void Method5(ref A a)
    {
        a = new A()
        {
            A1 = 10,
            A2 = 11
        };
    }

    private static void Method4(A a)
    {
        a = new A()
        {
            A1 = 10,
            A2 = 11
        };
    
    }

    private static void Method3(A a)
    {
        a.A1 = 6;
    }

    private static void Method2(string str)
    {
        str = "This is a new string";
    }

    private static void Method1(int i)
    {
        i = 5;
    }
```

[the output I expect vs the real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGL8W.png)

> I thought that output will be :
> i=0
>
> This is a string
> a.A1=5, a.A2=6
> a.A1=5, a.A2=6
> a.A1=10, a.A2=11
> but the output is :
> i=0
> This is a string
> a.A1=6, a.A2=6
> a.A1=6, a.A2=6
> a.A1=10, a.A2=11
>
> I will be glad to get explanation how method3 and method 4 are working.
> Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take a look at Method3(a)

```
private static void Method3(A a)
    {
        a.A1 = 6;
    }
```

The previous value was 5, right? Now it's declared as 6 and the official value is now 6. You are referring to the variable A1 and giving it a new value!

```
Console.WriteLine($"a.A1={a.A1}, a.A2={a.A2}");
```

So basically you override the new value (6) with the old value (5), because you're using a reference type.

So when we hop into **Method4(a)** the values are **A1 = 6 and A2 = 6**. The reason to why **Method4** isn't changing to **A1 = 10 and A2 = 11** is because you are not referring to anything. There is no reference type.
*It doesn't know that you're referring to the **object a** just because you passed the variable name as an argument*.

So you've pretty much initialised a new object of **class A** in **Method4** with no references. When it has no references, it doesn't know where to store the values in **Method(4)** hence why the values aren't changing.

If you look at **Method5(a)**, you use the "**ref**" keyword that means the ref keyword indicates that a value is passed by reference. The ref points at the object you have initialised at first.

I know it might be confused, but I can highly recommend using debug and then follow it step-by-step. Take your time, note down what is changing and like that you will understand much better.

Read these articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference
https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-c-sharp/modules/learn-csharp-references

If you find my post helpful, please upvote it.

Happy coding :-)